# What data-type shoud be chosen to represent a variable that takes fixed number of values?

Tags: c, types

I have a variable that can take any 3 values. If it can take only 2 values I would have assigned a bool type. But my variable can take 3 values. If I assign a int8_t type I am wasting 6 bits. Though this looks like preemptive optimization, I have millions of instances of this type, which is going to make a huge difference in memory usage.

What datatype should I assign the variable to such that least memory is used overall.

If I do it with enum, will that ensure less memory is used?

In particular what datatype should I use in C, Java, Python & MySQL.

Comment: "Millions", "huge difference", really? Even if you wasted a shocking *eight* bits on a million elements, that's like one megabyte. Unless you're programming for a washing machine (from the 1970s), I'd say leave this alone and do something more important.

Comment: But really, if this truly makes a difference, can't you just use `uint8_t` and bitmasks? (Here I have to disappoint you: `bool` is just typedeffed to `char` or `int` in most implementations...)

Comment: Moreover this is not counting the processing overhead that would cost to deal with bit fields compared to a single byte

Comment: If you are not doing anything with the remaining 6 bits, the compiler will reserve an 8 bits byte anyway to store the 2 bits.

Comment: @KerrekSB I am just making sure that I don't miss something better if it's there. It's actually in the order of billions in my use_case.

I also wanted to know how it's done in theory.

Comment: @Sravan: even my creepy touch screen tablet has gigabytes of RAM and could probably run your program... the point is, don't worry about this until there's a definite pressure for space. As I said in my answer, focusing on fast execution should be a higher priority as long as it's feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* (although I'm not sure it's the case) need this data type, you can use a bitfield. However, this could be constraining, since you can't define a pointer to such type. Wasting a bit:

```
struct s
{
  int n:2; /* 4 states instead of 3 */
};
```

Comment: This actually wastes *half* a bit ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain "int n:2;" syntax!!

Comment: @Sravan: It's called a "bit field". Look it up or search this site. It's a somewhat niche feature of C and C++.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit of math: naively you can describe each element with two bits, so you could pack four elements into one byte and get decent random access. Four elements have 3<sup>4</sup> = 81 states, so that's a usage of 81 / 256 ≈ 32%. If you want to stay on a byte boundary, you could look for the nearest power of three that fits into 2<sup>8</sup>, which is 3<sup>5</sup> = 243. In other words, if you one one byte to enumerate all possible states of five consecutive elements, you have a space efficiency of 243 / 256 ≈ 95%.

It makes no sense to do this packing in memory unless you're processing *vast* amounts of data and cannot fit everything into physical memory *and* can't partition your algorithm to run on smaller chunks at a time. For efficient computation, you should at the very least use a single byte (`uint8_t`), or even a machine word (`uint8fast_t`) to store your data. It's only when you serialize your data to disk and find that your terabytes of data are too expensive for your RAID-50 storage that you may wish to consider a complicated packing scheme. (Though then again you could just pipe your data through `gzip`, which basically does all that for you.)

---

Here's a rudimentary decoding algorithm for getting the five elements out of a byte:

```
unsigned int get_tristate(unsigned char const n, size_t const i)
{
  /* Conditions:   n in [0, 243)
                   i in [0, 5)

     Returns: the i^th trivalent element encoded in n, in [0, 2).
  */

    static unsigned int const powers[] = { 1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243 };

    return (n / powers[i]) % powers[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: Best answer imo. Storing in an array of 64 bits *unsigned long long*, `log3(2^64)` 3-values items per elements can be stored (40), using 63 bits out of 64. Efficiency ≈ 98%.

Comment: @ring0: Are you sure? I get an efficiency of 65% only, i.e. 3^40 / 2^64. How did you arrive at "63 bits"? In fact, 65% is just 95%^8, since the efficiency-per-byte is the same -- 5 elements per byte, or 40 per 8 bytes. Even with 128 bytes at a time you couldn't do better. At 256 bytes at a time, you get *one* extra 3-state element for free.

Comment: Actually going through the actual values doesn't give the efficiency since we are interested in the number of bits used against total of bits. For instance a "byte" efficiency is `log2(3^5) / 8` ie `7/8` or ≈ 88%. For 64 bits, efficiency can only be better, and we use `log2(3^40) / 64` bits. or `63 / 64` bits, which is ≈ 98%.

Comment: @ring0: Actually, it's really hard to come up with anything more efficient than five elements per 8-bit-byte. Even bytes with 7 or 9 or 10 bits would be much more wasteful.

Comment: @ring0: 5 elements per 1 byte is the same as 40 elements per 8 bytes. Both have the same information efficiency: log_2(3^5) / 8 is the same as log_2(3^40) / 64 (about 99%).

Comment: In my calculation above, I was using the approximation of number of integer bits fully used to store the `3^n` number, i.e. `floor(log2(3^n))`. Thus `7/8` for a byte, and `63/64` for a LL. But it would be more exact to take the actual value, ie `log2(3^n)` that gives `7.925` bits used for a byte (`99.06%`), and `63.399` bits for a LL (`99.06%`). So we have a tie :-) Actually when bits → ∞, efficiency → 1.